# Cumilative Split Factor of column in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which looks like this:

```
  A           B
1.2902      5.356
1.2         5.356
1.3         5.356
1.4         5.356
1.2         5.356
1.2         5.356
1.2         5.356
1.1         5.356
```

I want to get the values like below:

```
A             B
1.2902      5.356
1.2         4.151294373
1.3         3.193303364
1.4         2.280930974
1.2         1.900775812
1.2         1.583979843
1.2         1.319983203
1.1         1.19998473
```

Explaination:

```
If
A1 = 1.2902    & B1=5.356
A2=1.2      then B2 should be B1/A1 
A3=1.3      then B3 should be B2/A2
A4=1.2      then B4 should be B3/A3
A5=1.2      then B5 should be B4/A4
A6=1.2      then B6 should be B5/A5
A7=1.1      then B7 should be B6/A6
```

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Please specify calculation of all rows... Bit confused with the explanation.

Comment: Stop trying to use SQL as a spreadsheet. Tables or rowsets may have a passing resemblance to spreadsheets, but they're actually very different tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you have primary key in table and data are in sequence of primary key (i.e. no any missing record) then you can do it using recursive CTE like below

```
;with CTE as
(
   SELECT  Id,A,B FROM Test t1 WHERE Id = 1

   UNION ALL

   SELECT  t1.Id, t1.A, CAST(CTE.B/CTE.A AS decimal(18,10)) AS B
   FROM Test t1
   INNER JOIN CTE ON t1.Id - 1 = CTE.Id
)

SELECT * FROM CTE
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f788b/1)**